# How to use setContentView(int) from class which does not extend Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I need to call the setContentView(int) from my main Activity from another class which does not extends Activity.

In my custom class I've got the `private Context context;` var that is passed from the Activity in the Constructor but I can't figure out how to acces the Activity methods using the `context` variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your context is an instance of Activity class, simple class cast should work:

```
Activity a = (Activity) context;
a.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: This should work but I don't know why, the layout is not being actually changed..
I'm debugging and the code gets there and apparently it's executed but it has no effect..
I'm just doing:

Activity a = (Activity) context;
a.setContentView(R.layout.first);

Comment: With this solution, for example I can get the text from a TextView but I can't set the text because it's not being set.

Comment: @sergi Are you sure that it is executed within onCreate activity phase?

Comment: In my main Activity (in onCreate) I call the setContentView(int) and that works. Also in onCreate of my main Activity I create an object of a helper class and inside this helper class I need to eventually call the setContentView(int) from my main Activity.
This setContentView(int) call inside the helper class does not do anything.

Comment: nevermind, I was setting views from a wrong thread.. I don't know why it didn't crash, though.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (may not be the most elegant) is to pass the calling activity to the other class, not just the context.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass in a reference to the Activity you're using.

Something like this

```
class ActivityA extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle state){
      super.onCreate(state);
      ClassA myclass = new ClassA(this);
   }
}
```

And then Class A would have:

```
class ClassA {
   public ClassA(Activity yourActivity){
      ... Get your view here ....
      yourActivity.setContentView(view);
      ... do more things...
   }
}
```